# How to upgrade a django package only in a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, installation, package, virtualenv

I needed a virtual environment with all the global packages included. I created one, and the global Django version is 1.3.1. Now, I need to upgrade the Django version to 1.4 only in my virtual environment. I switched to my environment by activating it, and tried

> sudo pip install Django=1.4

It was installed,not in the virtual env but in the global dist-packages.

How to install a package only in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you switch to the virtual environment with the `activate` script. Just use `pip install Django==1.4` no `sudo` needed.

Alternately you can use `pip install -E=/path/to/my/virtual/env Django==1.4` in which case you don't need to switch to the virtual environment first.

Comment: thanks! You saved my time, coz I practiced to install modules in server with sudo.

Comment: It got installed in my whole machine, not just in the virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to upgrade a package and don't know the version number you want to upgrade to you can use

```
pip install <package_name> --upgrade
```

in your virtualenv. So in your case above the following would work as well:

```
pip install django --upgrade
```

Instead of `--upgrade` just `-U` is also enough.

Answer (score 0):

get your answer from

http://djangopaper.com/post/9334151791/install-multiple-django-version-using-virtualenvwrapper